# Recommendation letter dataset

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for a dataset containing academic recommendation letters, written in English, with as many following fields as possible:

- content of the letter
- date of the letter
- purpose of the letter (e.g., faculty application, visa application, internship application, etc.)
- relationship between recommendee and recommender
- demographics on recommendee and recommender

Comment: How do you properly anonymise such letters? I doubt very much that this can be turned into Open Data.

Comment: @jknappen That's one of the elements I am curious about :) maybe http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27264/903 (but for FERPA if in the US)+ manual checking. Also maybe more lenient outside the US.

Answer (score 2):

**Idea 1**: Troll google for personal letters of reference with a search engine - here are some samples:

- include the strings "letter of reference", "to whom it may concern"
- exclude the string "template"
- filter for PDF and DOC files

[example query](https://www.google.ch/search?q=%22letter%20of%20reference%22%20%22to%20whom%20it%20may%20concern%22%20filetype:pdf%20-template)

examples results [pdf1](http://www.beezleymanagement.com/upload/1247262688.pdf), [pdf2](http://www.alternativeoutput.it/refs_matteo_nastasi_eng.pdf), [pdf3](https://537010595dbeaf461ce6a715d51a1fe75e2fc644.googledrive.com/host/0B0VcL9sz2i6mQ3REVl9HSUk4V2M/letter5.pdf)

enhanced query:

- include degree (Master, PhD)
- include department (Physics, Law)

The downside is you'll have to do the categorization yourself

---

**Idea 2: (ethical?)** Post fake job advertisements on Craiglist or Indeed and ask people to send CV with letters of reference. At least one would then have geographical and topic-based categorization.

---

**Idea 3+:** There are plenty of less-ethical things beyond here. That being said, analysis of the hiring process is an important research topic and leads to important discoveries like - *[Are Emily and Greg More Employable than Lakisha and Jamal? A Field Experiment on Labor Market Discrimination](http://www.nber.org/papers/w9873)*.

Comment: 1 and 2 are not really suitable for academic letters. I'm also looking for letters, and would be happy with non-academic ones, too. 1 seems sort of reasonable, but a lot of work. Also, IRB approval is uncertain....

Comment: For mining google, it might be interesting to look at city council applications. They seem to be public in some cities, which could make the use legal.